# Query post using post id

Tags: wordpress

Someone can tell me what's the best way to get a post using its id?

I am using this:

```
$query = query_posts('post_id='.$_GET['php_post_id']);
global $post;           
foreach ($query as $post):

do stuff...

<?php endforeach;
 wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This is returning an array with all post

Answer (score 5):

```
get_post( $post_id, $output );
```

So in practice will look like:

```
$my_id = 7;
$post_id_7 = get_post($my_id);
```

Further reference about the post's parameters and fields, here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

**Update:** It's the **best practice** when you need to get a single post by id, no cicles required.

Answer (score 3):

Change `post_id=` to `p=`.

```
$setQuery = 'p='.$_GET['php_post_id'];
query_posts($setQuery);
```

Click in this link to see: [Retrieve a Particular Post](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Refer%C3%AAncia_de_Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o/query_posts#Retrieve_a_Particular_Post)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to get a single post with an ID you already know or getting from another source, i'll suggest the below code.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'p' => $id,   // id of the post you want to query
    );
    $my_posts = new WP_Query($args);  

   if($my_posts->have_posts()) : 

        while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post(); 

          get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'post' ); //Your Post Content comes here

        endwhile; //end the while loop

endif; // end of the loop.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a query like so:

```
  $rd_args = [
       'ID' => $postId
  ];

  $query = new WP_Query($rd_args);
```

And then you can retrieve the post from the query. Or set it to the global query and loop over it:

```
$GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $query;

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to fetch post using query_post if you know the ID.

```
<?php
    $my_query = query_posts('post_id=111&post_type=parks'); // in place of 111 you need to give desired ID.
    global $post;
    foreach ($my_query as $post) {
       setup_postdata($post);
       the_title();
       the_content();
    }
?>
```

Comment: I've been using this but do not know why was returning an array with all posts...i have fixed with this: <?php
   $args=array(
   'post_type' =>'post',
   'post__in' => array($_GET['php_post_id']),
    );
    $post_query = new WP_Query($args); 
    while ($post_query->have_posts()) : $post_query->the_post(); endforeach;

Comment: use the "p" parameter instead of your "post__in" to get just the one required post!