# Filter posts by related post's title or custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created two post types i.e., 'courses' and 'universities'. In courses, I created a relationship 'related_university' that connects courses to universities. However, I could not filter my courses by relationship values (title or any other field).

the following method works for me when I print the title of the related university:

```php
    $result[] = array(
                "id" => get_the_ID(),
                "title" => get_the_title(),
                "rel_university_name" => get_field("related_university")[0]->post_title,
                );
```

However, I get no results when I use the same method to filter my posts by the related university's title:

```php
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => get_field('related_university')[0]->post_title,
            'value' => $related_university_title,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Get all course attached to given university ?  
Maybe you have to take a look to the documentation: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/

Comment: But BTW, use title to query post is not a good idea. It's better to use ID. If you don't know how to that take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153741/query-post-using-post-id

Comment: Is there no way I can filter them by their title, meta or other fields?

Comment: For custom field check the link i send you before. And for title you can use 's' parameter of query (Initially used for search) or create a custom SQL Query.
Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040938/get-wordpress-post-by-post-title

Comment: I am filtering courses based on custom fields of related universities. The answer seems to filter posts by their own field, not related field. (For instance, I want to filter all the courses by their university's ranking or location). I prefer using WP_Query since there are more filters already attached to it.